# Can I stop an IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, configuration

In a .NET windows application to to modify a remote machine config file that is used by an ASP.NET application. However, I keep getting the error:

`System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '[file name]' because it is being used by another process.`

Now, this may not be the problem, but I'm figuring that if I can stop the IIS, then I can modify the machine config file (without getting the exception), and then I can restart the IIS using this code:

```
 Process proc = new Process();
            proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = "iisreset";
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = serverName;
            try
            {
                proc.Start();
                proc.WaitForExit();
                ...
```

1) Is there a way to stop the IIS *without* restarting it, and 2) Doe this approach to changing the server.config file even make sense?

(note, I am modifying the file with regular expressions search and replace; is this a problem?)

Comment: 1) type `IISRESET /?` at the command line

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that it is a remote machine config.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this. I don't have windows, so I can't check the exact name of the service, but I think it is "IISADMIN" or "w3svc". Remember this should be the service name and not the display name you see in the service control panel.

```
ServiceController controller  = new ServiceController();
controller.MachineName = "."; // or the remote machine name
controller.ServiceName = "IISADMIN"; // or "w3svc"
string status  = controller.Status.ToString();

// Stop the service
controller.Stop();

// Start the service
controller.Start();
```

You can also use

> net stop w3svc

or

> net stop IISADMIN

from the commandline or in your process in your code

Comment: I think 'w3svc' is better in this case, as that will only stop the web server. Stopping IISADMIN will also stop other services, like ftp and smtp.

Comment: yes, i think you correct, sorry, I don't have windows to check this

Comment: but the config file might still be locked by the admin service, you'll just have to check

Comment: +1 - using the service controller like this is a preferable way to control services than calling command line commands.

Comment: also, if you need to make sure the service has stopped (or started), you can call 'controller.WaitForStatus' after 'controller.Stop()' or 'controller.Start()'

Answer (score 4):

Strange. A .config file should not be locked exclusively.
But to answer your question, you can also use the net command for this:

```
net stop w3svc
```

to stop the www service, and

```
net start w3svc
```

to start it again.

You can also do this programmatically as described by @monkeyp

**Note** that I would advice against this and first try to determine (and resolve) the cause of the lock as described by @RichardOD.

Answer (score 3):

```
Using System.Diagnostics;

//to stop ISS
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("iisreset.exe", " /stop");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);

//to start ISS
ProcessStartInfo stopInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("iisreset.exe", " /start");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(stopInfo);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [IISRESET /STOP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/202013) command.

If you type IISRESET /? you will get a list of other available options.

[Edit: Pass the "/STOP" switch as the arguments property on the process' startinfo object.]

Answer (score 2):

Should be "iisreset /STOP" to stop the services, then "iisreset /START" to restart them.

Answer (score 2):

Use a tool like [wholockme or unlocker](http://www.bunnyhug.net/blog/archives/000063.php) to find the root cause of the locking.

Update- another option is to use [Process Explorer](http://blog.shijaz.com/2008/10/unlocking-files-that-are-in-use.html) (thanks fretje)- this is a good option as lots of developers have this utility on their PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can often just recycle or stop/start the [Application Pool](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/2245511) IIS is running, rather than restarting IIS altogether.